# Python script for deployment : comparing two folders to generate delta files to backup and ftp

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, continuous-integration

I am creating a python script for deployment by comparing two folders (`dev`, `prodmirror`) to generate delta files and then backup existing files and copy to `prodmirror` folder also ftp delta to server.

Below is the code..

**Issue**: def difference_dict(Dict_A, Dict_B) has to identify only A-B , but also returning if a file changed in B(i.e prodmirror), need some help/pointers here.

```
    import os
    import hashlib

    srcdir = 'C:\dev'
    tgtdir = 'C:\prodmirror'

    # definition of function to retrieve MD5 using small chunks of file
    def md5(fname):
        hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
        with open(fname,'rb') as f:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(2 ** 20), b""):
                hash_md5.update(chunk)
        return hash_md5.hexdigest()

    # definition of function to find dictionaries difference,i.e present in A not in B
    def difference_dict(Dict_A, Dict_B):
        output_dict = {}
        for key in Dict_A.keys():
            if key not in Dict_B.keys():
                output_dict[key] = Dict_A[key]
        return output_dict

    srcdict={}
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(srcdir):
       for filename in files:
        f = os.path.join(path, filename)
        srcdict[md5(f)]= f

    print("SRC Dict :"+str(srcdict))

    tgtdict={}
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(tgtdir):
       for filename in files:
        f = os.path.join(path, filename)
        tgtdict[md5(f)]= f
    print("TGT Dict :"+str(tgtdict))


    print("DIFF Dict :"+str(difference_dict(srcdict,tgtdict)))
```

Comment: I don't want to be annoying, but why are you writing this yourself? Why not use something like rsync that can do all this stuff and more?

Comment: because A)We need to sync between windows(local) and remote folder B)no tool we come come across does the exact job(like compare,create delta,backup delta, move delta to server)..rsync/lftp are unix only. so we left with scripting, choosen python for platform independency. any pointers welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after trying with few scripts and network lags for sync issues, the best free option we settled with is a free tool .. winscp , here is how to documentation --> https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_synchronize_full

advantages i found being able to sync in secured protocol in binary mode and auto watch facility(we don't use but good)
first replica, server folder copy in local and initiate a sync (2 modes available, auto/manual)

so what ever changes you do , tool will compare with server copy and move only changed files!

env we worked windows to linux.